# How to show wordpress category image on frontend

Tags: wordpress

I want this image to show on my frontend.

[image: **enter image description here**]

Kindly help me out.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try this code:

```
<?php
   $categories = get_the_category();
   foreach ( $categories as $category ) { 
   echo '<img src="' . esc_url( 'http://example.com/images/' . intval( $category- 
   >term_id ) . '.jpg' ) . '" alt="' . esc_attr( $category->name ) . '" />'; 
}
?>
```